# EditText inside of ListView causes redraw?

Tags: android

I have a ListView containing an EditText per item.
I set `android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"` on the ListView so I am able to type on the SoftwareKeyboard.
As long as I type only whitespaces everything is fine. The issue comes as soon as I start typing real words. That's when the little preview bar appears above the keyboard.
Then the ListView seems to be redrawn and the Focus gets set to the first EditText, causing all previous typed characters to be lost.
I also tried to set `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` but that did not work either.
Does anyone have an idea how to make this work? Thanks!

Comment: Since I found no answer yet I just tried to set the EditText.InputType to textNoSuggestions but my Samsung won't respect that property :/

Comment: You ever figure out a solution to this? I am having this same problem.